# How to get block data in Bukkit API?

Tags: bukkit

I had a block with this data:

```
{display:{Name:"{"text":"Монитор"}"},SkullOwner:{Id:[I;-1626538924,-1410775545,-1984946359,940139578],Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvODJmMTkxYTIyNjM5MzI1MjI2MmMyMmExNTQxY2FlNzkzNDlkMDExMmQzOTlkNmVjZjczOTU5MWQzZmM5NDdmIn19fQ=="}]}}}
```

How do I get this data from plugin?

Comment: This is not a block. It seems to be partially an itemStack. Also, can you show what you tried and add more tag ? It's in Java right ?

Comment: @Elikill58 Yes, Java. It is a placed block in the world, not in inventory

Comment: Yes but how did you get this ? Where it comes from ? Also, to get a block you need a location. You don't have it now. Your question is strange for me and I think you are missing something

Comment: @Elikill58 player interact event, I can get a block by getClickedBlock(), and then use getLocation(). Now I have a Location

Comment: @Elikill58 What to do next?

Comment: Just, in which version ? 1.8 ?

Comment: @Elikill58 1.16.5-1.17.1 (Multiver plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use NMS (`net.minecraft.server`) to get an NBT Tag.

Here is an example with 1.8.8 (v1_8_R3, tested with it), but just with your import this should works :

```java
Block block = event.getClickedBlock();
Location w = block.getLocation();
CraftWorld cw = (CraftWorld) w.getWorld(); // CraftWorld is NMS one
// For 1.8 to 1.12 :
TileEntity te = cw.getTileEntityAt(w.getBlockX(), w.getBlockY(), w.getBlockZ());
// for 1.13+ (we have use WorldServer)
TileEntity te = cw.getHandle().getTileEntity(new BlockPosition(w.getBlockX(), w.getBlockY(), w.getBlockZ()));
try {
    PacketPlayOutTileEntityData packet = ((PacketPlayOutTileEntityData) te.getUpdatePacket()); // get update packet from NMS object
    // here we should use reflection because "c" field isn't accessible
    Field f = packet.getClass().getDeclaredField("c"); // get field
    f.setAccessible(true); // make it available
    NBTTagCompound nbtTag = (NBTTagCompound) f.get(packet);
    plugin.getLogger().info(nbtTag.toString()); // this will show what you want
} catch (Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

The field name see to don't change accross version (always `c`).

Documentation:

- [Java reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html)
- [How to use NMS](https://www.alphr.com/use-nms-spigot/)

Comment: I'll check this later. Also, why try catch statement? I have already check - is it a player head? So, I don't need try catch statement.

Comment: The try/catch is necessary because of `getDeclaredField` and `get` method that have throw exception. And yes I test with Head

Comment: The method getTileEntityAt(int, int, int) is undefined for the type CraftWorld

Comment: You're right. I just edit my answer :)

Comment: It's worked, so I marked it as an answer.